# Restriction of Weierstrass $\wp$-function

Tags: special-functions, elliptic-functions

The general definition of the Weierstrass $\wp$-function involves the periods $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$. But at many places, the authors define the $\wp$-function with only one parameter, the periods ratio $\tau = \omega_2/\omega_1$. The relation is
$$
\wp(z; \tau) = \wp(z; \; \omega_1 = 1/2, \; \omega_2 = \tau/2).
$$
Is it possible to get the general $\wp$-function $\wp(z; \; \omega_1, \; \omega_2)$ from the "restriction" $\wp(z; \tau)$ ?

Comment: I believe that $\wp(\lambda z; \lambda \omega_1, \lambda \omega_2)=\lambda^{-2}\wp(z;\omega_1,\omega_2)$, which should be enough for you.

Comment: @Aphelli Yep. Would you know whether there is a similar relation for zeta Weierstrass? I'm going to search on Wolfram...

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found the answer::
$$
\wp(z; \; \omega_1/2, \; \omega_2/2) = \wp(z/\omega_1; \tau) / \omega_1^2. 
$$